# Mark UP this example (image inside).

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I can't figure out how to implement this example in HTML and CSS. I tried out a lot of ways but no one worked.
Any ideas?

Height of the text block is dynamic. Size of the image (a circle in this case) is fixed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI4kM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a div positioned absolute at the right side of each box, 100% height, with a transparent background image for the red dot:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <p>line 1</p>
    <p>line 2</p>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>line 1</p>
    <p>line 2</p>
    <p>line 3</p>
    <p>line 4</p>
    <p>line 5</p>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 300px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px; 
    margin-bottom:15px
}
.circle {
    position:absolute; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    top:0; right:-30px;
    background:transparent url('somepng') no-repeat 0 50%
}
```

check out this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKJZb/)

Answer (score 0):

On document.onReady function get the height of the div divide it by 2 and add the margin-top to the image as
if this is your html

```
 <div id="mdiv">
     <div id="sdiv">
         <p>ONE</p>
         <p>TWO</p>
        <p>THREE</p>
     </div>
     <img id="theimg" src="float:left;" src=""/>
    </div>
```

In document.onready do somthinglike this

```
$("#theimg").attr("margin-top",$("#mdiv").height()/2);
```

May not be the ideal question but it works

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/H79uj/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="left">
    <p>resize browser to see efect</p>
</div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
    height:50%;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
.circle {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:99;
}
```